# Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

I'm new at spring boot with kotlin.
I have error when application start up.
I had been seeking various solutions in the other answers in Stackoverflow.

But no answers gave me no solutions.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
Description:
Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.
Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
```

My `application.properties` configuration is following.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/db_name
spring.datasource.username=db_user
spring.datasource.password=db_pass
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

And `build.gradle.kts` is following.

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.2.0.RELEASE"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.8.RELEASE"
    war
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.50"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.3.50"
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.3.50"
}
group = "jp.co.blowfish.springboot"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
val developmentOnly by configurations.creating
configurations {
    runtimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom(developmentOnly)
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    runtimeOnly("mysql:mysql-connector-java")
    providedRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
        exclude(group = "org.junit.vintage", module = "junit-vintage-engine")
    }
}
tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

I have no idea what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It is missing the `port of Mysql` by default is `3306`

```
  spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name`
```

or `application.properties` is in `resources` folder.

Comment: I added port as you told me. However it is not working.